# Subgroups in semigroups vs monoids

Tags: semigroups, monoid, idempotents

Let $S$ be a semigroup (i.e. $S$ is endowed with an associative operation). With some work, one can prove that the idempotents of $S$ are in one-to-one correspondence with maximal subgroups of $S$: the correspondence associates to each idempotent $e$ the maximal subgroup $eSe$.

My question is: do we still get the same correspondence if $S$ were to be monoid? I think the answer should be yes since we would only need to add an identity element to $S$ to make it into a semigroup.

Comment: You say that, if $S$ is a monoid, you just have to add an identity element to make it a semigroup? I don't know, I can't put my finger on it, but that doesn't sound quite right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are confusing several things. First, if $e$ is an idempotent of $S$, $eSe$ is not a group, but a monoid with identity $e$. The correspondence you mention should map $e$ to the group of units of the monoid $eSe$, which is also the maximal subgroup of $S$ with identity $e$, or, equivalently, the $\cal H$-class of $e$.

The fact that $S$ is a monoid is irrelevant, since a monoid *is* a semigroup. If $1$ is the identity of $S$, then $1S1 = S$ and you just map $1$ to the group of units of $S$.

Finally, you mixed up things again in the last paragraph. It works the other way around. If $S$ is a semigroup which is not a monoid, you can add an identity to $S$ to get a monoid.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for clearing up my confusions. Does the maximality of the group of units of $eSe$ an immediate consequence of the maximality of $eSe$ as a submonoid?

Comment: What do you mean by the maximality of $eSe$ as a submonoid?

Comment: I mean maximality with respect to inclusion: if $M$ is a submonoid of $S$ containing $eSe$, then $M=eSe$.

Comment: Sorry, but your definition does not make sense. If $e$ is an idempotent, then $eSe$ is a monoid with identity $e$, but it is not maximal in your sense. You can only say that it is the maximal submonoid of $S$ with identity $e$.

Comment: I see, thank you again for the clarification.